# Delphi XE : Lost Library path

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have lost most of my Library Path in Delphi XE after upgrading from Delphi 2010,

Now even some simple app will fail to compile.

Is there any way to recover those lost directory entries that were in the library path?

**EDIT:** I found a surprising solution to this problem, just delete this registry key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0\Library

and restart Delphi, then the key in the registry will be generated again with the correct default values but you'll lose any third parties there, at least now it's working!

I Hope it's useful for anyone that is having the same problem :)

Comment: I found the same thing.   The XE library paths where missing on one of my machines,  I added them all by hand.   Not sure what the cause was.

Answer (score 5):

For me this happened after installing VirtualTreeview 4.8.7 (? 5?) in Delphi XE under win7X64.
I tried the delete reg path above (after saving it off to a file) and no go.

Then I noted that there was a dropdown in the library path that remembered previous changes to the whole path. Set it (and all the other remembered ones) back a step or two and everything compiled.

Sooo, then I reimported the originally bad one watching for differences. Right there in the topmost line

$(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\release
was
$(Platform)\release    (in the incorrect version)

Modified to have the full line in and all is well.
$(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\release

I expect this is because the installer strips these out and rebuilds them, but treats this as two lines instead of one.

Scotto the Unwise
(spellcheck for the win)

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have your Delphi 2010 install around?  You could just copy the library path from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's none, if they aren't saved accidentally somewhere on your hard drive. But the safe way is to make a clean reinstall of Delphi, then reinstall all the components.

Comment: Been there, done that.  Unfortunately in my case that didn't fix it because as per scottostanek it's due to one of the component packages that it got broken in the first place.  scottostanek has the right solution, simply go and edit the lib path and fix the first entry. :)