# Default Library Path

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, library-path

Prior to my problem, I attempted to install a component which required me to change my Library - Win32 library path. The installation did not work out so I left it. A few days ago, I ran Delphi to work on my project. I compiled the program but Delphi told me "Unit not found: 'Systems.pas' or binary equivalents (.dcu) so I changed the Library path to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\lib. I was then able to compile my program but when I clicked a button, none of the code ran!

I went back to check my syntax and everything was correct hence why I was able to compile my program (note: my code and program was left untouched for weeks). I then tried to re-install Delphi (2 times) expecting that the Library Path would fix, but it didn't.

After the failed attempts of trying to restore default settings I did some researched on stackoverflow but I could still not find the answer. Topics I've come across:

[Delphi XE : Lost Library path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822993/delphi-xe-lost-library-path)

[Delphi can't find System.dcu; what should the default path settings be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517308/delphi-cant-find-system-dcu-what-should-the-default-path-settings-be)

I added the ShowMessage function to test if it worked and it did so I really have no clue what the problem is. However I am still suspecting that my Library Path is incorrect.

What do you guys think the problem could be?

- my code
- or my IDE library path

Note: current library path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\lib

Also, how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517308/delphi-cant-find-system-dcu-what-should-the-default-path-settings-be) should solve you problem. If you need specific data for Delphi 2010, here is the registry file for 64-bit Windows (for 32-bit Windows the registry branch should be [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\Library]):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\Library]
"Browsing Path"="$(BDS)\\SOURCE\\WIN32\\VCL;$(BDS)\\source\\Win32\\rtl\\common;$(BDS)\\SOURCE\\WIN32\\RTL\\SYS;$(BDS)\\source\\Win32\\rtl\\win;$(BDS)\\SOURCE\\WIN32\\WEBSNAP;$(BDS)\\source\\ToolsAPI;$(BDS)\\SOURCE\\WIN32\\IBX;$(BDS)\\source\\Win32\\Internet;$(BDS)\\SOURCE\\WIN32\\PROPERTY EDITORS;$(BDS)\\source\\Win32\\soap;$(BDS)\\SOURCE\\WIN32\\XML;$(BDS)\\source\\Win32\\db;$(BDS)\\source\\Indy\\Indy10\\Core;$(BDS)\\source\\Indy\\Indy10\\System;$(BDS)\\source\\Indy\\Indy10\\Protocols;$(BDS)\\source\\database;"
"Debug DCU Path"="$(BDS)\\lib\\Debug;$(BDS)\\Lib\\Debug\\Indy10;$(BDS)\\RaveReports\\Lib"
"Language Library Path"="$(BDS)\\lib\\$(LANGDIR);(BDS)\\lib\\$(LANGDIR)\\Indy10"
"Package DCP Output"="$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\\Dcp"
"Package DPL Output"="$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\\Bpl"
"Package Search Path"="$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\\Bpl"
"Translated Debug Library Path"="$(BDS)\\lib\\$(LANGDIR)\\Debug"
"Translated Library Path"="$(BDS)\\lib\\$(LANGDIR)"
"Translated Resource Path"="$(BDS)\\lib\\$(LANGDIR)"
"Search Path"="$(BDS)\\lib;$(BDSUSERDIR)\\Imports;$(BDS)\\Imports;$(BDS)\\Lib\\Indy10;$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\\Dcp;$(BDS)\\include;$(BDS)\\RaveReports\\Lib"
```

---

If plain import of the above registry file does not help:

1. Reboot and try again;
2. If the problem persists, delete
   `Software\CodeGear\BDS\7.0` branches from both
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\` hives and reinstall
   Delphi;
3. Never run automatic installation procedure for unknown
   component packages on your working system.